# pandas str.replace is not working properly

Tags: python, pandas, string

I want to replace specific Strings within another String in my .csv file.

While

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("file.csv", sep=";",encoding='iso-8859-1')
df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.replace('Corona', '')
```

is correctly removing the word Corona from Coronavirus,

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.replace('\xc3\xa4', 'ä')
```

ist not working to replace the given String.
Where is the mistake?

Comment: Can you add a few lines which are giving you problems? not required the entire content of file.csv, but a few examples

Comment: Try using a raw string: `r'\xc3\xa4'`

Comment: You could also try running .decode().  This might work, too: `df.loc[:, "Column"].str.decode("utf-8")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data["column_name"] = data["column_name"].apply(lambda x: x.replace("characters_need_to_replace", "new_characters"))
```